# Query one for column headers, query 2 for row data

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I would like to know how to use asp.net vb to create a gridview that has one query be the column headers then use those column headers to populate the table. I have accomplished this in asp classic but would like to know how to to it in .net. The following are my queries that accomplish this in asp classic.

```
Select DOA,GroupName From Groups Where Doa is not null Order by zDOA
```

I use that query to populate the top of my table, then use this to get the users and their groups.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  TM.PersonID, GroupMembers.FullNm, TM.zUpdatedOn, Location.LocationName FROM GroupMembers INNER JOIN TM ON GroupMembers.PersonID = TM.PersonID Inner JOin Location ON Location.LocationID  = GroupMembers.LocationID  INNER JOIN  Groups ON GroupMembers.GroupsID= Groups.ID WHERE (GroupMembers.zIsActive = 1) AND GroupMembers.LocationID = "&LocationID&" AND Groups.DOA IS NOT NULL order by FullNm
```

That query gets people's name, their location(from StringQuery) and then finds out which groups they are in. When it cycles through which groups they are in, it compares their groups to all of the groups. When they match I put a check box in the correct spot. I have attached a image of this. The RED is from the first Query and the BLUE is from the second query. My question is how to replicate this in .net. I am unable to put the first query as the columns and fill in the rest with the second query.

![Example] [image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the sql pivot function. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query